# Angular 1.5 - $ngOnInit detect initialization only and not reload or vice versa

Tags: angularjs

I am using the `ngOnInit` lifecycle in angular 1.5 and I have a scenario where I want to distinguish between the initial load of a component and a refresh (ie `$state.reload`). how can I make this distinction in a components controller?

Comment: This isn't really doable, AFAIK.  due to how `reload` works, the previous instance of the controller isn't present in memory anymore, and the new instance of the controller goes through its entire initialization process as if it were the first time it is accessed (because it *is* the first time this instance is accessed).

Comment: in other words, `$state.reload` **is not** a refresh.